# how to parse and get data from xml in java

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I have this XML code:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <string xmlns="https://www.cvlkra.com/">tTKyEndh0iBqnZdjpUntEQ%3d%3d</string>
```

I want to get this: ***tTKyEndh0iBqnZdjpUntEQ%3d%3d*** for which I have tried the below code:

```
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder1 = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document document = builder1.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(string)));
    Element rootElement = document.getDocumentElement();
    String nodeName = rootElement.getNodeName();
```

But i am not getting it. I am getting null value instead of **tTKyEndh0iBqnZdjpUntEQ%3d%3d** even when I have tried some other code also.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `getTextContent()` instead `getNodeValue()` returns null because it has no values.

Answer (score -1):

You should not use getNodeName() instead use rootElement.getNodeValue(). May be this helps.

Comment: He stated getNodeName() returns null, this is a different thing

Comment: The OP stated `i am getting null value` Please look at my answer.